# url path with image variable in image source uri React Native

Tags: react-native, image, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to display an Image in which the data was fetch from an api and render into a flatlist, I am trying to concat or connect the sting link with the variable, in the image source uri but did not work, how can I fix it.

```
<FlatList 
data = {data}
keyExtractor={item => item.id}
showsVerticalScrollIndicator = {false}  
renderItem={({item}) => {
   return (

    <Image 
            source={{ uri: `https://placewave.com/avatar/${item.user_image}` }}
            resizeMode="cover"
            style={styles.userImage}
    /> 

   )
}}
/>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the respond, but I find the answer

First I define the url `const URL = 'https://placewave.com/avatar';`

Then Include it:

```
<Image 
     source={{ uri: URL + '/' + item.user_image}}
     resizeMode="cover"
     style={styles.userImage}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it will not work in such way.
Image must not have conditional `source` prop. Consider moving `https://placewave.com/avatar/${item.user_image}` to a variable and add condition to display some kind of fallback(like ActivityIndicator) until you will have valid `user_image`.

Comment: I am a beginner in this programmer can you help edit my code or is this what you met I should do  `const imageBaseURL = "https://placewave.com/avatar/;
const avatar = { imageBaseURL + item.artist_image } ;
<Image source={{ avatar }} />`

Comment: You don't understand what I said, I did the code my self, I said I am a beginner, just for proper understanding, the is why I said you can edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

**Complete test code**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const data = [{ id: 1, user_image: 'cute-boy-standing-little-white-background-40214306.jpg' }, { id: 1, user_image: 'no image url.jpg' }]
  return (
    <View >
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          let uriVar
          if (item.user_image) uriVar = `https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/${item.user_image}`
          return (<View>
            {uriVar != null ?
              <Image source={{ uri: uriVar }}

                style={styles.userImage}
              /> : null} </View>)
        }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Hello
      </Text>

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  userImage: {
    width: '150px',
    height: '150px',
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: @Repheal still did not work, this time I got an error Text string must be rendered

Comment: you test the code at https://snack.expo.dev/

Comment: use this data to see the effect of the conditional statement                             `const data =[{ id:1, user_image:'cute-boy-standing-little-white-background-40214306.jpg'  }, { id:1  }]`